# translating english description of c-variable into a c-style variable declaration, using BNF syntax

Tags: c, grammar, bnf

Hello I'm trying to write a grammar that translate english c declaration into c-style variable declaration, for example:
    "x is an array of 10 pointers to int",
    "x is a pointer to pointer to char",
    "x is a pointer to struct of type type-struct"
    <->
    int *x[10],
    char **x,
    struct type-struct *x.

My attempt:
    "{means that there are 0 or more items}"

```
description ::= id declaration type
declaration ::= declarator
declarator  ::= pointer|function|array
pointer     ::= pointer-to {pointer-to} function|array
array       ::= array-of-n {pointer-to}
function    ::= function-that-return {pointer-to}
type        ::= int|char|short|float...|spec-struct
spec-struct ::= struct type-struct
```

I want to know if this grammar is fine to build a recursive descent parser.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply calling `cdecl`? If so, what's your specific issue?

Comment: I want to know if this grammar is fine to build a recursive descent parser. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be, this is sufficient. But, I would suggest you to see whether your grammar is fine with the help of a [LEX](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html) and [YACC tool](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/index.html).